# Assume $X \subset \operatorname{span}(Y)$ and $Y \subset \operatorname{span}(X).$ Prove $\operatorname{span}(X) = \operatorname{span}(Y).$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $X,Y$ be sequences or subsets of a vector space $V$ over a field $F.$ Assume $X \subset \operatorname{span}(Y)$ and $Y \subset \operatorname{span}(X).$ Prove $\operatorname{span}(X) = \operatorname{span}(Y).$

Proof. Suppose that $X \subset \operatorname{span}(Y)$ and $Y \subset \operatorname{span}(X)$ and let $v \in \operatorname{span}(X).$ Then $v = c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_k x_k$ where $c_i \in F$ and $x_i \in X.$ Since $X \subset \operatorname{span}(Y),$ it follows that each $x_i \in \operatorname{span}(Y).$ Since $\operatorname{span}(Y)$ is a subspace of $Y,$ it is closed under scalar multiplication so that every $c_i x_i \in \operatorname{span}(Y)$ and it is closed under addition so that $c_1x_1+\cdots+c_kx_k = v \in \operatorname{span}(Y).$ Hence $\operatorname{span}(X) \subset \operatorname{span}(Y).$ Similarly, $\operatorname{span}(X) \supset \operatorname{span}(Y),$ and so $\operatorname{span}(X) = \operatorname{span}(Y).$

Is my proof correct? Thanks for the help

Comment: One minor thing, span$Y$ is not a subspace of $Y$, as $Y$ itself may not be a subspace of $V$. span$Y$ is a subspace of $V$ however, and the rest of the proof seems fine to me.

Comment: A different proof is to note that by defintion $\text{span}(S)$ is the smallest linearly-closed space that contains all the points in a set $S$. Therefore if $W$ is any linearly-closed space with $S \subset W$, then automatically $\text{span}(S) \subset W$. Therefore $X \subset \text{span}(Y)$ implies $\text{span}(X) \subset \text{span}(Y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important correction: you wrote

> Since $\operatorname{span}(Y)$ is a subspace of $Y,$ it is closed under scalar multiplication so that every $c_i x_i \in \operatorname{span}(Y)$ and it is closed under addition so that $c_1x_1+\cdots+c_kx_k = v \in \operatorname{span}(Y).

which is incorrect.  One correct way to fill in the gap is to write something like

> Thus, there are coefficients $d_{ij}$ such that $x_i = \sum_{j=1}^k d_{ij}y_j$.  So, we have
>   $$
> v = \sum_{i} c_ix_i = 
> \sum_{i} c_i \sum_{j} d_{ij} y_j = 
> \sum_{j} \left(\sum_{i}c_i d_{ij}\right)y_j
> $$
>   which means that $v \in \operatorname{span}(Y)$.

You may also want to consider a proof along the lines of Paul's comment.